# Perl MooseX::Declare with method attributes MooseX::MethodAttributes

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to use [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose), [MooseX::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Declare), and [MooseX::MethodAttributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::MethodAttributes) to be able to use `class` and `method` keywords instead of `package` and `sub` and at the same time get the methods attributes, so I need this form of packages and methods:

```
class Moosey {
    method connect ($user, $pass) : Action GET  {...}
}
```

If I use `sub` keyword it will work with attributes but of course no method signatures, If I use `method` keyword, it will hang the script if I use method attributes.

Below is the code I am trying:

```
package Moosey;

use Moose;
use MooseX::Declare;
use MooseX::MethodAttributes;

class  Moosey {

    # this works fine
    sub moosey : Action { print "moosey called"; }

     # this line hangs the script
     # Error: Can't locate object method "attributes" via package "MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method"
    #method  moosey  : Action { print "moosey called"; }

    # this also does not work   
    #method  moosey  : Get ($name, $email) { print "moosey called"; }
}

1;
my $class = Moosey->new;
my $attrs = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->attributes;
print "@$attrs";
```

My question is does these Moose modules allows me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MooseX::Method::Signatures (which is what MooseX::Declare uses to handle methods) does support attributes, but they need to appear *after* the signature, not before it:

```
method foo :MyAttr ($arg1, $arg2) {  # NO
    ...;
}

method foo ($arg1, $arg2) :MyAttr {  # YES
    ...;
}
```

However, it *does not seem to work* with MooseX::MethodAttributes because they both try to override Moose's default metaclass for methods.

I would like to be able to say "use [Moops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops) instead". But that seems to fail for a different reason. A workaround is to declare the allowed attributes in `UNIVERSAL`...

```
use Moops;

package UNIVERSAL {
   use Sub::Talisman qw( Action Get );
}

class Moosey using Moose {
   method moosey1 :Action(FOO,BAR,BAZ) {
      say "moosey1 called";
   }
   method moosey2 (Str $name = "Bob", Str $email?) :Get {
      say "moosey2 called $name";
   }
}
```

Moops provides nice introspection for method signatures:

```
my @params = Moosey->meta->get_method("moosey2")->signature->positional_params;
say $_->name for @params;  # says '$name'
                           # says '$email'
```

But it doesn't provide much in the way for attributes. (Yet.)

**TL;DR:** no.

Comment: I tried this code based on your correction:

`use MooseX::Declare; 
use MooseX::MethodAttributes; 
class  Moosey {
method moosey ($fname, $lname) : AttrMoosey AttrBoosy AttrCoosy { print "moosey called"; } }`

 then use Data::Dumper;
my $class = Moosey->new;
my $attrs = $class->meta->get_method('moosey'); print Dumper($attrs);` 

and I can see the attributes in the object hash dumped, is there any way to access this attributes hash direct for each method.

Comment: I was able to get a list of methods attributes direct using the code `my $attribute_list = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_list; 

my $attribute_map = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_map;
print Dumper($attribute_list);
print Dumper($attribute_map);
`

The problem is they are stored by a numeric keys do not know how to get it, not by the method name. Can you help on this?