# Perl MooseX::MethodAttributes get method attributes

Tags: perl, moose

When using [MooseX::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Declare) and [MooseX::MethodAttributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::MethodAttributes) in the same package I get error when getting the method attributes using:

```
$attrs = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->attributes;
```

I get the error:

```
Can't locate object method "attributes" via package "MooseX::Method::Signatures::Meta::Method"
```

I tried to look at the code for the module `MooseX::MethodAttributes` and I was able to get
these methods to work about attributes:

```
my $attribute_list = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_list;

my $attribute_map = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_map;
```

The issue here is the module uses a numeric pointer to the attributes which I do not know how to generate to get specific method attributes.

If I run this code:

```
my $attribute_list = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_list;
my $attribute_map = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_map;
print Dumper($attribute_list);
print Dumper($attribute_map);
```

I get this debug information:

```
$VAR1 = [
          70862136
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          '70862136' => [
                          'AttrMoosey',
                          'AttrBoosy(path/app)',
                          'AttrCoosy'
                        ]
        };
```

So how can I get the method attributes in this case until these modules are fixed to work with each other properly.

Here is the code I use for testing:

```
package Moosey;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Declare;
use MooseX::MethodAttributes;

class  Moosey is mutable {
    method moosey ($name, $email) : AttrMoosey AttrBoosy(path/app) AttrCoosy { print "moosey called"; }
}
1;

use Data::Dumper;
my $class = Moosey->new;
my $method = $class->meta->get_method('moosey');

# this does not work:
# my $attrs = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->attributes;

my $attribute_list = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_list;
my $attribute_map = $class->meta->get_method('moosey')->associated_metaclass()->_method_attribute_map;
print Dumper($attribute_list);
print Dumper($attribute_map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713962/40468), MooseX::MethodAttributes would need to be fixed to respect the original method metaclass, rather than imposing one.

Comment: I see you are the author of the module `MooseX::MethodAttributes` on cpan [https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::MethodAttributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::MethodAttributes), any plan to release this fix soon?